# Jquery li onclick add class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu in my master page.

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="."><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.aspx"><span>contact us</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

when I click on the menu item, I want to set css class using jquery

```
 $(function () {

            $("li:first-child").addClass("test");
            $('li').click(function () {
                $(this).addClass('test');

            });
        });
```

css

```
 .test {background-color:Red;}
```

when clicking on the menu, it shows the background color but then it disappears. how do i make it stay active until a different menu is clicked?

thank you

Comment: I tested it in FF, Chrome and IE7,8. Worked fine. http://jsfiddle.net/9qgzk/

Comment: Do you have any other code effecting these list items?

Comment: Won't the "contact us" link navigate to another page? You'd need to set the background again on that other page.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE2: this is not a javascript problem

```
<li><a href="#"><span <%=ServerSizeLogic.SelectedMenu("Home")%>>Home</span></a></li>
```

This is a nasty guess on how the server side might to it, depending on your server side technology. `ServerSizeLogic.SelectedMenu("Home")` or whatever you use would either return an empty string or "class='test'". Just make sure only one of your li elements gets the style and remove the client side code

```
// don't do it like this but hopefully you get the gist
ServerSizeLogic::SelectedMenu(string item){
    if (item == CurrentPage)
      return "class='test'";
    return "";
}
```

UPDATE: obviously once you navigate away from the page the element you want to be selected will have to come from the server (unless you are using ajax), in which cast just get rid of the `li:first-child` and set the class directly in your view code on the current `li` element

Original:
How about this little fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LmUrP/

```
 $(function () {

        $("li:first-child").addClass("test");
        $('li').click(function () {
            $('#menu li').removeClass('test');
            $(this).addClass('test');
        });
    });​
```

html

```
<ul id='menu'>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>contact us</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>apples</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>bananas</span></a></li>
</ul>​
```

Comment: You put `href='#'` based on what? you know that the page would reload with the original html.

Comment: yes the # was for the fiddle, which I realised after posting that, the actual problem was unrelated unless the OP was using ajax, updated response accordingly just before I saw you comment.

Comment: because he said `it shows the background color but then it disappears.` and that's because the page "reloaded"

Comment: thanks all for your help, so I remove li:first-child, how do I set so on page reload the background is still on? all of my code inside the master page, do I need to add the jquery inside each aspx page as well?

Comment: post updated, pick one li element, via your repeater, server side control, mvc view or whatever and add the test class in the master page based either on the page the user is on or some other server side state. no jQuery required.

Answer (score 1):

This will make you able to highlight the "current list item" based on the current page url
You'll have to test on the url on load:

```
$(function () {
    $('ul#menu>li>a[href="'+location.pathname+'"]').addClass('test');      
});​
```

have your html like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/contactus.aspx"><span>contact us</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

notice the `/` on the beginning of href attribute value!
that's because `location.pathname` always returns an absolute path.

here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/29E23/
i wrote `href="/_display/"` because that's the url of jsfiddle's display iframe !

**BUT** if your page is in `http://domain.com/folder/page.php` you will have to write `href='/folder/page.php'` to have the right behavior!

Comment: Won't adding `/` to the href break the link, given that it _was_ a relative link?

Comment: yes that's the issue here! but putting /folder/page.php will fix it
Thank you